# How do I ignore this Eclipse file in Git?

Tags: eclipse, git, ignore

I tried adding it to my global *.gitignore* but it is still showing up as an untracked file when I do `git status`.

```
researchProject/.externalToolBuilders/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator (4).launch
```

I disabled the JavaScript validator because it kept giving my build errors -- the only solution I found was to disable it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add the following lines to your `.gitignore` file:

```
.project
.settings
.classpath
.metadata
```

and for your case also

```
.externalToolBuilders
```

and you should be good to go.

Do not add `.project` and `.classpath` to `.gitignore` if you are working on an eclipse-specific project.

Comment: What do you mean by eclipse-specific project. I have an Eclipse project and assume that I can `.gitignore` `.settings` (there is no `.metadata`) but not `.project` or `.classpath`.

Comment: Eclipse-specific means that the project is designed to be developed in eclipse only, using eclipse as build tool, not just the IDE. Regular maven or gradle projects are supposed to be IDE-agnostic. A `.pom` file should contain all necessary information for the project to be built with or without an IDE. And a `.project` file has no value for for an IntelliJ user.