# .gitignore not ignoring folder

Tags: git, laravel, smf-forum

I have a project in Laravel and I have forum in public directory which I don't want to push it to repository, so I write in .gitignore:

```
### Laravel ###
vendor/
node_modules/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
bootstrap/cache/
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env

# SMF
public/forum/

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
```

However, the entry still appears in **Git status**
Here is my tree with it:
+...
+ public
++ forum
+++...
+...
Where is the problem?

Directory structure
[image]

Git status
[image]

Comment: Can you show us directory structure?

Comment: I doubt there is path issue.

Comment: Show the (relevant part of) the output of `git status`. (Everything but the other paths is relevant, in case you're wondering.)

Comment: Generic solution would be add `*` to start and end of `public/forum`.

Comment: @KishorPawar - I added screens

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that this folder is already in your index (you committed it at an earlier moment). Changes to files in the index will always be in "git status". Only new files in that folder will be ignored.

To fix it. See my answer on 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38304114/2274140

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: If you want to remove the file from git, but actually keep the file locally you can use `git rm --cached -r path/to/folder`, the --cached flag will remove it from git's knowledge but actually keep the file. The only thing about using this method is whilst it keeps the file locally, it will remove it from any other systems that pull the remote changes.

Answer (score 34):

In .**gitignore** add

```
public/forum
```

Run

```
git rm --cached -r public/forum
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem and does, like me, want to keep those files there, I simply:

1. Cut / paste all the files into a different folder outside of my repo.
2. Committed the changes to git (aka committed the deletions)
3. Pasted the files back in

Good to go, and the files no longer reappeared. Hopefully your case will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

- git was not ignoring `build/` directory for a Java project when I had added `build/` in my `.gitignore`
- i tried changing it to `build/*` without luck

finally removing the slash `/` by keeping just `build` in `.gitignore` worked

---

PS: my `build` directory was never checked in (`git add`ed), just that it was lying around and git kept reporting it under `Untracked files`

Answer (score -3):

Do the following to trigger the `gitignore`:

1. Commit all your pending changes in the repository which you want to fix and push that.
2. Remove everything from the git index in order to refresh your git repository. This is safe. Use this command:

   ```
   git rm -r --cached .
   ```
3. Add everything back into the repo, which can be done using this command:

   ```
   git add .
   ```
4. Commit these changes, using this command:

   ```
   git commit -m "Gitignore issue fixed"
   ```